# Assign list of dicts to functions in a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Say I have a list of dicts containing payload data for GET requests, like the following:

`lst = [{'json1': 1},{'json2': 2},{'json3': 3}]`

This list can be of arbitary length in a range of 1 - 10. From here I am sending this list to a for loop of threads, that call independent functions (`call_1` through to `call_10`):

```
for k in lst():
    thread.start_new_thread(call_1, ( lst[k] ,))
    thread.start_new_thread(call_2, ( lst[k] ,))
    ...
    thread.start_new_thread(call_10,( lst[k] ,))
```

My question is, if the list is only of length 3, say, what method should I use so that I only call the first 3 threads?

Any suggestions welcome, thanks.

Comment: Please can you show us what `k` ?

Comment: @Adi219 `k` is a dict `{'json1':1}` etc.

Comment: Ohh ... I've edited my answer :)

Comment: Are your functions _really_ named `call_1`, `call_2`, etc? Why don't you put them into a list?

Comment: @PM 2Ring no, just trying to make the question accessible.

Comment: @@PM 2Ring the functions need to be independent because they each access an independent TCP socket, so numbering them, or using some kind of sqeuential marker is the only way im affraid.

Comment: You can name them anything you like. But it will be easier to loop over them if you put them into a list.

Comment: ANd even if you do need a bunch of independent functions, you can probably _create_ them in a loop using a function that returns functions.

Comment: @PM 2Ring I can't put them in a list because of the way threads are called, i.e. `(call_1, ({'json':1} ,)`

Comment: So what? Let's say the list of functions is called `funcs`. Then you can do `(funcs[1], ({'json':1} ,)`, etc. BTW, you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Comment: @ajsp How is that a problem? Just iterate over your list of functions like `for func in func_list: thread.start_new_thread(func, ( lst[k] ,))`

Comment: @PM 2Ring, @Aran-Fey you're right guys, that is the way to go.     
`for k, j in enumerate(qurey_lst): thread.start_new_thread(func_list[k],( j ))`

Comment: @Aran-Fey  should I delete this question then?

Comment: Excellent. There's no need to delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
counter = 0
for k in lst:
    counter += 1
    exec("thread.start_new_thread(call_" + str(counter) + ", ( lst[k] ,))" )
```

I'm using `exec()`, which treats strings as code. The string in question is being dynamically created using `counter`.

Comment: I thought about trying this but I have reservations about calling threads in exec. I get this error """unqualified exec is not allowed in function "multi_call" because it contains a nested function with free variables [line 61]"""

Comment: This won't work because the functions aren't actually named like that.

Comment: @ajsp Honestly speaking, I don't know why that's happening ...

Comment: Please don't spread bad programming practices. The correct solution here is to store the functions in a list and use a loop to iterate over them.

Comment: @PM2Ring Then it's the OP's job to edit the code as they haven't told us what the functions *are* named as